# Akka stream test with testkit and scalatest

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-stream, akka-testkit

I am getting NullPointerException when testing my akka stream app with scalatest and don't understand why... I probably missed something in Akka Streams I am just diving into it.

I use the common structure of code for scalatest with scala 2.12.4 and sbt 1.0.3
This is my app

```
object CdrToMongoReactiveStream extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("cdr-data-generator")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext=materializer.executionContext
  import RandomCdrJsonProtocol._

  val randomCdrThrottledSource : Source[RandomCdr,NotUsed]= Source
    .fromIterator(() => Iterator.continually(RandomCdr(msisdnLength,timeRange)))
    .throttle(throughput,1.second,1,ThrottleMode.shaping)
    .named("randomCdrThrottledSource")

  val cdrJsonParseFlow : Flow[RandomCdr,String,NotUsed]= Flow[RandomCdr]
    .map((cdr: RandomCdr) => cdr.toJson.toString())
    .named("cdrJsonParseFlow")

  val mongodbBulkSink : Sink[String,NotUsed] = Flow[String]
    .map((json: String) => Document.parse(json))
    .map((doc: Document) => new InsertOneModel[Document](doc))
    .grouped(bulkSize)
    .flatMapConcat { (docs: Seq[InsertOneModel[Document]]) ⇒
      Source.fromPublisher(collection.bulkWrite(docs.toList.asJava))
    }
    .to(Sink.ignore)

  val f = randomCdrThrottledSource.via(cdrJsonParseFlow).runWith(mongodbBulkSink)
}
```

And my test file

```
class CdrToMongoReactiveStreamSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  import RandomCdrJsonProtocol._

  "randomCdrThrottledSource" should {
    "generate RandomCdr elements only" in {
      val future = CdrToMongoReactiveStream.randomCdrThrottledSource
        // line 30 in the error
        .runWith(Sink.head)(CdrToMongoReactiveStream.materializer)

      val cdr = Await.result(future,10.second)
      cdr shouldBe a [RandomCdr]
    }
  }
  "cdrJsonParseFlow" should {
    "parse RandomCdr to correct json format" in {
      val randomCdr = RandomCdr("+33612345678",1511448336402L,"+33612345678","SMS","OUT",0,0,0)
      val (pub,sub) = TestSource.probe[RandomCdr]
        .via(CdrToMongoReactiveStream.cdrJsonParseFlow)
        .toMat(TestSink.probe[String])(Keep.both)
        .run()

      sub.request(1)
      pub.sendNext(randomCdr)
      sub.expectNext() shouldBe equal(randomCdr.toJson.toString())
    }
  }
}
```

And the error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CdrToMongoReactiveStreamSpec.$anonfun$new$2(CdrToMongoReactiveStreamSpec.scala:30)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1078)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec.withFixture(WordSpec.scala:1881)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1076)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.runTest(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.runTest$(WordSpecLike.scala:1070)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec.runTest(WordSpec.scala:1881)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:396)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.runTests(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.runTests$(WordSpecLike.scala:1146)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec.runTests(WordSpec.scala:1881)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run(Suite.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run$(Suite.scala:1129)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec.org$scalatest$WordSpecLike$$super$run(WordSpec.scala:1881)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.$anonfun$run$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.run(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.run$(WordSpecLike.scala:1190)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpec.run(WordSpec.scala:1881)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1340)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1334)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1500)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

Comment: Probably one of the values on line 30 is null. Have you tried printing them or using your IDEs debugging tools to figure out which one it is? It's not clear which line was line 30 in the original file, since you seem to have removed some lines since running it. Can you please add the lines to your question, or, if they aren't important, run the test again without the lines so that we get a useful stack trace?

Comment: The error doesn't make sense for your code.  The null pointer exception addresses `CdrToMongoReactiveStreamSpec.scala:30` but your code snippet is only 25 lines long.

Comment: Sorry i simplified the code for readiness. Line 30 is the runwith(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem declaring Source, Flow and Sink outside of the main program

```
object CdrToMongoReactiveStream {

  def randomCdrThrottledSource(msisdnLength : Int,timeRange : Int, throughput : Int): Source[RandomCdr,NotUsed]= {
    Source
      .fromIterator(() => Iterator.continually(RandomCdr(msisdnLength,timeRange)))
      .throttle(throughput,1.second,1,ThrottleMode.shaping)
      .named("randomCdrThrottledSource")
  }

  def cdrJsonParseFlow : Flow[RandomCdr,String,NotUsed]= {
    import RandomCdrJsonProtocol._

    Flow[RandomCdr]
      .map((cdr: RandomCdr) => cdr.toJson.toString())
      .named("cdrJsonParseFlow")
  }

  def mongodbBulkSink(collection : MongoCollection[Document], bulkSize : Int) : Sink[String,NotUsed] = {

    Flow[String]
      .map((json: String) => Document.parse(json))
      .map((doc: Document) => new InsertOneModel[Document](doc))
      .grouped(bulkSize)
      .flatMapConcat { (docs: Seq[InsertOneModel[Document]]) ⇒
        Source.fromPublisher(collection.bulkWrite(docs.toList.asJava))
      }
      .to(Sink.ignore)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f = randomCdrThrottledSource(msisdnLength,timeRange,throughput)
      .via(cdrJsonParseFlow).runWith(mongodbBulkSink(collection,bulkSize))

    logger.info("Generated random data")
  }
}
```

and the test file

```
class CdrToMongoReactiveStreamSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  import CdrToMongoReactiveStream._
  import RandomCdrJsonProtocol._

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("cdr-data-generator")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val collection = new Fongo("mongo test server").getDB("cdrDB").getCollection("cdr")
  val randomCdr = RandomCdr("+33612345678",1511448336402L,"+33612345678","SMS","OUT",0,0,0)

  "randomCdrThrottledSource" should {
    "generate RandomCdr elements only" in {
      val future = CdrToMongoReactiveStream.randomCdrThrottledSource(8,86400000,1)
        .runWith(Sink.head)

      val cdr = Await.result(future,5.second)
      cdr shouldBe a [RandomCdr]
    }
  }
}
```